# Tomcat handshake_failure when https call from the tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat8

I have a Java 8 application running on a tomcat (v8.0.44) on a docker container. 
This application call an external `https` url (I can't provide the url) and i get the following error :

> Exception: class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Received fatal
>   alert: handshake_failure at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>   at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)

This error happend only with the same url. Other `https` urls works fine.

I can't reproduce this behavior on a `Spring boot` application. So i guess the issue is on the tomcat or the container configuration.

Do you have any suggestions about the origin of this issue.

Thanks.

**EDIT** :

When I add the option `-Djavax.net.debug=all` I have this output :

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-nio-8080-exec-5, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1535552913 bytes = { 156, 140, 20, 250, 150, 107, 55, 72, 40, 86, 58, 240, 204, 254, 26, 209, 76, 216, 97, 145, 48, 238, 91, 155, 53, 179, 190, 112 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 209
0000: 01 00 00 CD 03 03 5C 87   AE 91 9C 8C 14 FA 96 6B  ......\........k
0010: 37 48 28 56 3A F0 CC FE   1A D1 4C D8 61 91 30 EE  7H(V:.....L.a.0.
0020: 5B 9B 35 B3 BE 70 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  [.5..p..d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 40 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  @...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00D0: 02                                                 .
http-nio-8080-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
[Raw write]: length = 214
0000: 16 03 03 00 D1 01 00 00   CD 03 03 5C 87 AE 91 9C  ...........\....
0010: 8C 14 FA 96 6B 37 48 28   56 3A F0 CC FE 1A D1 4C  ....k7H(V:.....L
0020: D8 61 91 30 EE 5B 9B 35   B3 BE 70 00 00 64 C0 24  .a.0.[.5..p..d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 40 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....@..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
http-nio-8080-exec-5, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-5, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-nio-8080-exec-5, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-5, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, the java version that not include the UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 files. I upgrade java from version `8u131-b11` to `8u201-b09`.